# How to add an image picker to the main storyboard xcode swift?

Tags: uikit, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I want to add the feature of choosing an image from you images in IPhone on an Iphone application in Swift, I wanted to know the given features and how much I can do with them. 
   I need the basic features which will allow me to browse the albums and choose in image which will eventually be loaded in my UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing to retrieve image from gallery in swift will work as to make your view controller class as should have implement delegate methods of UIImagePickerControllerDelegate. Make the top of your class look something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self
}
```

ButtonTapped action we made earlier, and we’ll call up the UIImagePickerController there:

```
@IBAction func loadImageButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, which gives 3 options:

1. UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
2. UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
3. UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum

   ```
      func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

          if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
             imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
             imageView.image = pickedImage
         }

       dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
      }
   ```

Comment: Is that helpful to you?